# Set a default value to a rich:select component which has enableManualInput set to true?

Tags: java, jsf, drop-down-menu, richfaces, default-value

```xml
<rich:select id="miDisabled" enableManualInput="false" value="bar">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="foo" itemValue="foo" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="bar" itemValue="bar" />
</rich:select>

<rich:select id="miEnabled" enableManualInput="true" value="bar">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="foo" itemValue="foo" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="bar" itemValue="bar" />
</rich:select>
```

Both `rich:select`s have `"bar"` value selected by default, but `miDisabled`'s dropdownlist has two available values `"foo"` and `"bar"` as expected, while `miEnabled`'s only have `"bar"`: `"foo"` *disappeared*...

Any other way to set a default value to a `rich:select` component which has `enableManualInput` set to `true`?

---

- RichFaces 4.1.0
- JSF 2.1.21
- JDK 6u20 x32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the default value is being set, isn't it?

With manual input enabled the dropdownlist is filtered by what you type in. If you want to show all items all the time you have to set `clientFilterFunction` for `rich:select`.

```
filter = function(discardTypedValue, item) {
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Oh right, I didn't get this point, many thanks :) For those who could be interested too, [here](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&sample=clientFilter&skin=blueSky) is how `clientFilterFunction` can be overwritten.